# Is the World 4 version of Hunt impossible without doing something else first?

Tags: braid

I'm stuck on the World 4 version of Hunt. I don't want a walkthrough; I don't even want a hint. (*Please* don't offer a hint.) I just want to know whether it's impossible without doing something else first to alter the puzzle, because it sure looks impossible to me: <strike>as far as I can tell, the rightmost guy will always be alive when you get to the gate.</strike> Just kidding; I got it.

Comment: It's possible to beat *all* the levels without doing something else first.

Comment: @Wipqozn while it is possible to beat every level without doing something else, OP is referring to grabbing the puzzle piece in the level. Some puzzle pieces in the game cannot be obtained the first pass through (the specific example that comes to mind for me is early on in the game, world not disclosed to avoid spoilers).

Comment: @Kotsu: if you're thinking of the example I'm thinking of, that's what had me worried.

Comment: @Kotsu yeah that occurs to me now as well, I'm quite certain that is the *only* instance though.

Comment: @Wipqozn As far as puzzle pieces are concerned, it's the only instance, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is completely possible to do without doing anything else outside the level. I was skeptical at first as well, but you just have to think about it a bit.

As requested, no hint has been given.

Comment: If this was a sufficient answer to your question, an "accept" would be appreciated ;).

Comment: If an answer is accepted, it means it has been useful, and thus could be considered a hint. Shall we agree to disagree?