# How to solve the World 4 hunt?

Tags: braid

Now that we've [determined](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27643/is-the-world-4-version-of-hunt-impossible-without-doing-something-else-first) that the World 4 hunt level of Braid is solvable without doing anything special outside the level, the question remains:

How to solve this level?

Comment: I went ahead and added the spoiler tag, since braid is about as spoilerable as they get.

Comment: @Aubergine eh. If you don't want spoilers just don't open this question.

Comment: @badp Isn't that, like, exactly what the spoiler tag is for?

Comment: No, as we discussed in chat. We have better tags than just "spoiler", tags that say exactly what is it you're spoiling. "spoiler" should only be used, IMHO, for question titles that have spoilers.

Comment: IMHO, we should never, ever have spoilers in a question title.

Comment: @Arda Spoilers in question titles are sometimes a necessity to get questions that can be searched for.

Comment: @badp Then put the question to be searched for in the body.

Comment: @badp let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1052/discussion-between-arda-xi-and-badp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to kill every monster like in World 2. However, with time tied to movement, if you move to the left of where (and when) you killed a monster, you'll undo the kill, so you'll have to kill them by jumping on them and moving right.

So, move to the far left of the level and make a note of where all the monsters are. You'll have to kill them in order from left-most to right-most.

First, the one at the very top, then the one on the mid-left platform (by jumping using the monster on the mid-right, not using the ladder), then the left one on the bottom. Then the one on the lower platform on the right*, and then the one on the mid-right.

The door is time-independent, so it will stay unlocked from this point on.

---

*For the penultimate monster, you'll want to get a higher jump by jumping this one twice. First, jump on him moving to the left so you get the boost without killing him, and then finish the jump moving to the right so you end up on the platform while killing him.

Comment: So one of the things I was stuck on is that I couldn't figure out how to get to #6. You can't do it just by jumping on #5 once. After I asked my question, I realized I could do it by jumping on #5 _twice_ (on the first jump, go slightly backwards so #5 comes back).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right, I forgot, I'll add that in.